# Place category_description in the meta description (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags, categories

Header in my theme I created the following code for the meta description:

```
<?php if (is_single() || is_page()) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo metadesc($post->ID); ?>" />
<?php }else{ ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

and included this code in my function.php:

```
function metadesc($pid) {
$p = get_post($pid);
$description = strip_tags($p->post_content);
$description = str_replace ("\n","",$description);
$description = str_replace ("\r","",$description);
if (strlen($description) > 150) {
return htmlspecialchars(substr($description,0,150) . "...");
}else{
return htmlspecialchars($description);
 }
}
```

now I want to also incorporate category_description the theme header :

```
<?php if ( is_category() ) { echo category_description(); } ?>
```

can you help me how can I do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the work mostly done:

```
<?php
    if( is_single() || is_page() ) $description = strip_tags($post->post_content);
    elseif( is_category() ) $description = category_description();
    else $description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    $description = substr($description,0,150);
?>

<meta name="description" content="<?= $description ?>" />
```

As you see, I would forget about all the cleaning you are doing in `metadesc()`, just get rid of the html with `strip_tags()`, but I see no need to remove linebreaks or to translate to html entities, certainly I don't think search engines will mind at all about a line break or either a `&` or a `&amp;`.

Plus, there is no need to check the length of the description. Just try to truncate it, if its length is less than 150 chars, `substr()` will return the whole string untouched.

**EDIT:**
Responding to your comment, you can do it this way if you prefer to use the `metadesc()` function you were using:

```
function metadesc() {
    global $post;

    if( is_single() || is_page() ) $description = strip_tags($post->post_content);
    elseif( is_category() ) $description = category_description();
    else $description = get_bloginfo( 'description' );

    $description = substr($description,0,150);

    return $description;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I did not understand then how do I change the code in functions.php?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have updated my previous answer so you can continue to use your function.