# Meta description

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

With the help of the answer given at [Place category_description in the meta description (wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727909/place-category-description-in-the-meta-description-wordpress) I think I've got this almost figured out, but it just doesn't seem to be working - when I view the page source for any page, the meta description is empty:

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

Here's what I've got:

In functions.php

```
<?php
if( is_single() || is_page() ) $description = get_the_excerpt();
elseif( is_category() ) $description = category_description();
else $description = "Free French lessons and language tools from Laura K. Lawless, including verb conjugations and bilingual articles to help you improve your reading and listening comprehension.";
$description = substr($description,0,500);
?>
```

In header

```
<meta name="description" content="<?= $description ?>" />
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function, it will return something in most cases.

```
// functions.php
function blog_description() {
    $content = get_queried_object();

    if ( is_singular() ) {  
        $content = !empty( $content->post_excerpt ) ? $content->post_excerpt : ( !empty( $content->post_content ) ? $content->post_content : $content->post_title );
        return str_replace( PHP_EOL, ' ', substr( wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $content ), 0, 155 ) );

    } elseif ( is_category() ) {        
        $content = !empty( $content->description ) ? $content->description : get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ' - ' . $content->name;       
        return str_replace( PHP_EOL, ' ', substr( wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $content ), 0, 155 ) );    
    }

    return get_bloginfo( 'description' );
}

// header.php
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo blog_description(); ?>" />
```